# Buttons get clipped when I resize the window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl with MinWidth and `MinHeight` set.

There a grid and many controls inside.

I have another `Grid` inside the main grid. The inner grid's code is as below.

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" helpers:RowHeaderNumber.DisplayRowNumber="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
              RowHeaderWidth="40" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              Margin="10,65,20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ExpressionCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" SelectionChanged="ExpressionGrid_SelectionChanged" PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="ExpressionGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
     <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ExpressionContextMenu}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,20"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF1F0F0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="Ok_Button_Click" Margin="0,0,112,10"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="Cancel_Button_Click" Margin="0,0,20,10"/>
    </Grid>
```

The buttons in the bottom get clipped when I resize the window. What changes should I make to make the `DataGrid` resize when the window is resized?

Comment: set `DataGrid`s `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`

Comment: @faztp12 Buttons still get clipped.

Comment: Is there a `Width` or `Height` set for the `DataGrid` ? If so, remove it

Comment: No. I only have `RowHeaderWidth` set for the `DataGrid`. That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: could you update your question with the full XAML ? :)

Comment: Ok. There is a lot of code though.

Comment: Where you have closed the DataGrid ? The code which you have posted shows Buttons(OK/CANCEL) with Grid.Row set and present inside DataGrid. This does not make sense. Check closing tag of DataGrid, and take out your OK/CANCEL buttons out of your DataGrid.

Comment: I just forgot to add the closing tag. The buttons are not inside the `DataGrid`. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you want your buttons to remain fully visible, then you have to apply minimum width to your window, else there is no limit to make your window small. A window of 10x10 is practially of no use. Some minimum width is a must to keep your application sensible big.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Button 1"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,0,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

The above code doesnt clip the Buttons. 
Remember not to set Width and Height

`PS`: It will Clip when the `Window` Width is less than 50 and in such similar cases :) thats obvious :)

Comment: Okay. It's still clips in my system. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: :( I'll play around with it for sometime and let you know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Margins are added to all the controls. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Nop. The row acts as a Grid to its contents and Margin places them inside the row just like how it does in normal grids :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Margin & width from the button. the problem should be. if the width goes less then 75+120 + 75 + 20 it will start clipping the button. I would suggest not to use the width & margin instead use extra row & column in your grid & set it accordingly. also do give min & max height or min & max width to your user control to control it overall.

See the following example

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Width="50" Margin="20"></Button>
        <Button Width="50" Margin="20" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>


in This example buttons will always clip when you resize & decrease the size of your window.
```

But if you use it like this it will never clip

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"></Button>
</Grid>
```